# C# -Extract substrings from string with change in content

Tags: c#

```
(WHERE)
  (CONDITION OPERATOR="AND")  
   (EXPRESSION NAME="abc" ATTRIBUTE="minor")
   (VALUE)m1(/VALUE)
   (/EXPRESSION)

  (EXPRESSION NAME="abc" ATTRIBUTE="ID")
  (VALUE)ID(/VALUE)
  (/EXPRESSION)

  (EXPRESSION NAME="abc" ATTRIBUTE="major")
  (VALUE)m2(/VALUE)
  (/EXPRESSION)

(/CONDITION)     
(/WHERE)
```

How can i get 3 substrings from the string as maybe minor = the first `substring` with `attribute = "minor"`, then string `Id=` the next substring with attribute `Id` and so on, as the the expression name may change and i cannot use the string as a whole to get the value of `ID` in `(VALUE)ID(/VALUE)`. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: It's not clear...

Comment: I mean i need to extract 3 substrings from the above string, depending upon the "Attribute" in each "Expression" and store in different variables.

Comment: Is that some kind of Xml where you replace <> by () ?

Comment: It looks like you can turn this text to xml and use XPath

Comment: 1/. Is this your real input or is it an XML redacted for Reason? 2/. What is your expected output? No sentence, just the value, your sentence about what you want are really unclear. I want substring is not precise enought. There is an infinit amount of substring of your string for those 3 variable what is their string value you expect.

Comment: My guts tell me that you have an Xml and this will end up a dupliacte of "how to deserilise an xml attribute"

Comment: This part is inside CData in an xml.

Comment: My expected output would be 3 strings with the following:                        string minor= "(VALUE)m1(/VALUE)"
string id= "(VALUE)ID(/VALUE)"
strin major="(VALUE)m2(/VALUE)"

Answer (score 1):

Your input have a regular structure so it is possible to convert it to xml:

```xml
<WHERE>
  <CONDITION OPERATOR="AND">
    <EXPRESSION NAME="abc" ATTRIBUTE="minor">
      <VALUE>m1</VALUE>
    </EXPRESSION>
    <EXPRESSION NAME="abc" ATTRIBUTE="ID">
      <VALUE>ID</VALUE>
    </EXPRESSION>
    <EXPRESSION NAME="abc" ATTRIBUTE="major">
      <VALUE>m2</VALUE>
    </EXPRESSION>
  </CONDITION>
</WHERE>
```

and then query it with xpath like `//EXPRESSION[@ATTRIBUTE='major']/*[1]`

While simple `string.Replace` may work I think it would be better to replace only braces that not inside attribute values. You can use a regular expression to find strings:

```
"([^"\\]|\\.)*"
```

and extract strings bounds:

```
var stringsBounds = Regex.Matches(input, "\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => new
    {
        begin = m.Index,
        end = m.Index + m.Length - 1
    })
    .ToArray();
```

with this bounds you can do smart replacing:

```
Func<Match, bool> isInsideString = m => stringsBounds.Any(b => m.Index > b.begin && m.Index < b.end);
var xmlAsText = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(input, "\\(", m => isInsideString(m) ? "(" : "<"),
    "\\)", m => isInsideString(m) ? ")" : ">");
```

Now you are ready to query your xml:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlAsText);

var expressionSelector = "//EXPRESSION[@ATTRIBUTE='{0}']/*[1]";

foreach (var attribute in new [] {"minor", "major", "ID"})
{
    var xpath = string.Format(expressionSelector, attribute);
    var node = xml.XPathSelectElement(xpath);

    Console.WriteLine($"Attribute: {attribute}, element: {node}");
}
```

You can try it [online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ch4eMX)

Comment: Thanks will try it!